# Time-based triggeri in Google Sheets is not firing

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

I've created a time-based trigger like I always do in google sheets. However, the puzzling piece is that this one doesn't fire.

I've enabled the trigger and the executions show that the script is running every minute. However, the script does not execute as expected. I have a debug message in the script that is showing up in the stackdriver logs which is fun.

If I manually run the script it runs fine. Why is this happening?

This is my script:

```
    function fillFormula() {
    // this script will change the date format to the correct one

 //   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  console.log({message: "My timed trigger function is running", inputs: arguments});

 // var formulas = rows.getFormulas();

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var ss1 = ss.getSheets()[0];
    var rows = ss.getDataRange();
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
    var sh = ss.getActiveSheet(), lRow = sh.getLastRow(); 
  var lCol = sh.getLastColumn(), range = sh.getRange(2,5,1,1);
  if(numRows>2){
  range.copyTo(sh.getRange(3, 5, numRows-2, 1), {contentsOnly:false});}
  //var newRange = sh.getRange(lRow+1,1,1,lCol);
//newRange.setFormulas(formulas);
    var dateVal = ss1.getRange(numRows,4).getValue(); 
  var timeStamp = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm");
  if(dateVal==""){
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange(numRows, 4).setValue(timeStamp);
  }
}
```

Comment: I think several people are having issues at the moment. Over the last week a few of my spreadsheets haven't fired any installed onEdit triggers for a few hours, then started working again. It's really frustrating. Maybe this is affecting you, too?

Comment: Ah gotcha yeah that makes sense thanks!